# dos batch : using double quotes with IF

Tags: batch-file

I have a DOS-batch like this :

```
@echo off
if "%1" == "%2" GOTO next
echo different
goto end
:next
echo same
:end
```

Are the double quotes surrounding `%1` and `%2` necessary ? In which case are they useful ?

Comment: Also, make sure %1 and %2 don't contain double quotes themselves. The if will start failing with a (not so) helpful error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an expression before and one after the ==. If %1 or %2 is empty than you would get an syntax error.